# Ansible Docker containers dynamic inventory on MacOS

Tags: docker, ansible

I have started a Docker container using the following command:

```
docker run tomcat:latest
```

Then I created a file named docker.yml with the following contents:

```yaml
plugin: community.docker.docker_containers
docker_host: unix://var/run/docker.sock
```

Finally I try to obtain a list of the currently running Docker containers using:

```
ansible-inventory -i docker.yml --list
```

However instead of a list of running containers, I only get the following result:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse docker.yml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse docker.yml with constructed plugin: Incorrect plugin name in file: community.docker.docker_containers
[WARNING]: Unable to parse docker.yml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

Have I misunderstood the Ansible Docker containers dynamic inventory or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you install the collection containing that plugin, as prompted in the notes: `ansible-galaxy collection install community.docker`?

Comment: Yes and I even did a forced reinstall.

Comment: Tried this in Ubuntu 20.04 and encountered no issues after having done "sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock" to remedy a permission denied error encountered when fetching (Docker) server API version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect I had a case of system in disarray and this was the cure:

- I retained my current Python installation located at *~/Library/Python/3.9/*.
- Attempted to uninstall Ansible using pip:

  ```
  pip uninstall ansible
  ```
- Manually removed all things Ansible:

  ```
  sudo rm -r /etc/ansible
  sudo rm -r -/.ansible
  sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible*
  sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ansible*
  ```
- Performed a fresh installation of Ansible:

  ```
  pip install ez_setup
  pip install --user ansible
  ```
- Installed Ansible Docker collection prerequisite:

  ```
  pip install docker
  ```
- Installed Ansible Docker collection:

  ```
  ansible-galaxy collection install community.docker
  ```

After the above, the Ansible Docker container dynamic inventory works as expected and without errors.